# How to apply string methods to multiple columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple string columns.  I want to use a string method that is valid for a series on multiple columns of the dataframe.  Something like this is what I would wish for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['123f', '456f'], 'B': ['789f', '901f']})
df

Out[15]: 
      A     B
0  123f  789f
1  456f  901f

df = df.str.rstrip('f')
df
Out[16]: 
     A    B
0  123  789
1  456  901
```

Obviously, this doesn't work because str operations are only valid on pandas Series objects.  What is the appropriate/most pandas-y method to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Function [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) working with `Series` so is possible use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip('f'))
```

Or create `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.stack().str.rstrip('f').unstack()
```

Or use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.rstrip('f'))
```

Last if need apply function to some columns:

```
#add columns to lists
cols = ['A']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip('f'))
df[cols] = df[cols].stack().str.rstrip('f').unstack()
df[cols] = df[cols].stack().str.rstrip('f').unstack()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can mimic the behavior of `rstrip` using `replace` with `regex=True`, which can be applied to the entire `DataFrame`:

```
df.replace(r'f$', '', regex=True)
```

```
     A    B
0  123  789
1  456  901
```

Since `rstrip` takes a sequence of characters to strip, you can easily extend this:

```
df.replace(r'[abc]+$', '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension and feed to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```
res = pd.DataFrame({col: [x.rstrip('f') for x in df[col]] for col in df})
```

Currently, the Pandas `str` methods are inefficient. Regex is even more inefficient, but more easily extendible. As always, you should test with your data.

```
# Benchmarking on Python 3.6.0, Pandas 0.19.2

def jez1(df):
    return df.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip('f'))

def jez2(df):
    return df.applymap(lambda x: x.rstrip('f'))

def jpp(df):
    return pd.DataFrame({col: [x.rstrip('f') for x in df[col]] for col in df})

def user3483203(df):
    return df.replace(r'f$', '', regex=True)

df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit jez1(df)         # 33.1 ms per loop
%timeit jez2(df)         # 29.9 ms per loop
%timeit jpp(df)          # 13.2 ms per loop
%timeit user3483203(df)  # 42.9 ms per loop
```