# How to split a column in a data frame containing only numbers into multiple columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-processing

I have a .dat file containing the following data:

```
0001100000101010100
110101000001111
101100011001110111
0111111010100
1010111111100011
```

Need to count number of zeros and ones in each row

I have tried with Pandas.

- Step-1: Read the data file
- Step-2: Given a column name
- Step-3: Tried to split the values into multiple columns. But could
  not succeed

```
df1=pd.read_csv('data.dat',header=None) df1.head()
                 0   1100000101010100

1   110101000001111
2   101100011001110111
3   111111010100
4   1010111111100011

df1.columns=['kirti']
df1.head()
        Kirti
_______________________
0   1100000101010100
1   110101000001111
2   101100011001110111
3   111111010100
4   1010111111100011
```

I need to split the data frame into multiple columns depending upon the 0s and 1s in each row.

the maximum number of columns will be equal to max no of zeros and ones in any of the rows in the data frame.

Comment: Can you provide the output you are expecting

Comment: First, you should probably read your file as a string, otherwise you will loose "0" at the beginning. For strings, there is the count method. mystr.count("0") will give the number of "0" in mystr.

Comment: COL1 | COL2 | COL3| .......|COLN
             ---------------------------------------------
ROW0      1     |      1   |      0  |  ......|  0      
--------------------------------------------------------
ROW1      1     |      1   |      0  |  ......|   1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create one column `DataFrame` by parameters `names` and `dtype=str` for convert column to strings:

```
import pandas as pd

temp="""0001100000101010100
110101000001111
101100011001110111
0111111010100
1010111111100011"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), header=None, names=['kirti'], dtype=str)

print (df)
                 kirti
0  0001100000101010100
1      110101000001111
2   101100011001110111
3        0111111010100
4     1010111111100011
```

And then create new `DataFrame` by convert values to `list`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in df['kirti']])
print (df)

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12    13    14    15    16    17    18
0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1     0     1     0     1     0     0
1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1     1     1  None  None  None  None
2  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1     1     0     1     1     1  None
3  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  None  None  None  None  None  None
4  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0     0     1     1  None  None  None
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a list of strings, then use the [count](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm) method:

```
>> data = ["0001100000101010100", "110101000001111", "101100011001110111", "0111111010100", "1010111111100011"]
>> for i in data:
    print(i.count("0"))

13
7
7
5
5
```

If your data is in a .dat file with whitespace sepparation as you discribed, then I would recommend loading your data as follows:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.dat", lineterminator=" ",dtype="str", header=None, names=["Kirti"])
    Kirti
0   0001100000101010100
1   110101000001111
2   101100011001110111
3   0111111010100
4   1010111111100011
```

The `lineterminator` argument ensures that every entry is in a new row. The `dtype` argument ensures that it's read as string. Otherwise you will loose leading zeros.

If your data is in a DataFrame, you can use the count method (inspired from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52099068/how-to-apply-string-methods-to-multiple-columns-of-a-dataframe)):

```
>> data["Kirti"].str.count("0")
0    13
1     7
2     7
3     5
4     5
Name: Kirti, dtype: int64
```

Comment: The data in the data files are